# Disable system notification for new MMS message programmatically?

Tags: android, mms

`abortBroadcast()` is used for disabling system notification for new SMS messages, but is there anyway to do it for new MMS messages? I've tried using `abortBroadcast()` but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Edit: 
I have tried using the following codes so that my application will catches the intent first, but it prevents the MMS message from entering my inbox.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <receiver android:name=".MMSReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

To be more specific, is there any way to detect system notifications for new MMS messages and suppress them programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
public class MmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        abortBroadcast();

    }

}
```

Note: In your manifest file add the BroadcastReceiver -

```
<receiver android:name=".listener.MmsListener">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS"/>
```

Comment: it seem that Android broadcasts this event as unordered message. Anyone can confirm?

Comment: the broadcast confirms that it is ordered (isOrderedBroadcast() == true), but still no way of aborting it

Comment: It doesn't work for me either, however it must be possible since apps like WhatsApp does it in 'Phone Verification' section with a simple SMS sent to the same mobile phone. It hides the SMS notification and reads the content in background.